# Loading many tables in Cloud Data Fusion fails with DAG error

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I have an MS SQL Server data source with around 1000 tables, which I need to put into BigQuery. I was hoping to use Data Fusion to load them all into staging tables in BigQuery, and then perform transformations on them afterwards. However, as soon as I create a pipeline with two "islands" it give a DAG error. Is that a feature or a just something I'm doing wrong? I can't find anything in the documentation. My pipeline looks like this:

[image]

And the error I get when I try to deploy is: "Invalid DAG. There is an island made up of stages BigTest,BigQuery BigTest (no other stages connect to them)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each pipeline is a single DAG (Directed acyclic graph) and all the source and sink should be connected for the configuration to be valid. You can use multi-table source plugin that can bring in multiple tables at once to a landing table in BQ.

[image: Multi Table plugins from Hub]

You can use Multi table plugins and BQ Multi table sink for your use-case.
[image]

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I didn't know about those plugins, thanks a lot! I'll try that.

Comment: Is this plugin worked?. I am facing an issue as its not working giving error related to spark/tables/schema.